# Subset sum recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, subset-sum

I will be happy to get some help.

I have the following problem:

I'm given a list of numbers `seq` and a target number and I need to write 2 things:

1. A recursive solution that returns `True` if there is a sum of a subsequence that equals the target number and `False` otherwise. 
   example:

   ```
   subset_sum([-1,1,5,4],0)   # True
   subset_sum([-1,1,5,4],-3)  # False
   ```
2. Secondly, I need to write a solution using what I wrote in the previous solution
   but now with memoization that uses a dictionary in which the keys are tuples:
   `(len(seq),target)`

For number 1 this is what I got to so far:

```
def subset_sum(seq, target):
    if target == 0: 
        return True
    if seq[0] == target:
        return True
    if len(seq) > 1:
        return subset_sum(seq[1:],target-seq[0]) or subset_sum(seq[1:],target)
    return False
```

Not sure I got it right so if I could get some input I will be grateful.

For number 2:

```
def subset_sum_mem(seq, target, mem=None ):
    if not mem:
        mem = {}
    key=(len(seq),target)
    if key not in mem:
        if target == 0 or seq[0]==target:
            mem[key] = True
        if len(seq)>1:
            mem[key] = subset_sum_mem(seq[1:],target-seq[0],mem) or subset_sum_mem(seq[1:],target,mem)
        mem[key] = False

    return mem[key]
```

I can't get the memoization to give me the correct answer so I'd be glad for some guidance here.

Thanks for anyone willing to help!

Comment: Any reason you're not just using [`@memoize`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize)?

Comment: Probably because it's homework ;)

Comment: Please tag as homework if this is in fact homework.  People will still help.  It is good form and can help people understand where you are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here's a solution using dynamic programming:

```
def positive_negative_sums(seq):
    P, N = 0, 0
    for e in seq:
        if e >= 0:
            P += e
        else:
            N += e
    return P, N

def subset_sum(seq, s=0):
    P, N = positive_negative_sums(seq)
    if not seq or s < N or s > P:
        return False
    n, m = len(seq), P - N + 1
    table = [[False] * m for x in xrange(n)]
    table[0][seq[0]] = True
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        for j in xrange(N, P+1):
            table[i][j] = seq[i] == j or table[i-1][j] or table[i-1][j-seq[i]]
    return table[n-1][s]
```

Comment: Very nice. Alternative: `def positive_negative_sums(seq):
    return sum(e for e in seq if e >= 0),
        sum(e for e in seq if e < 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I have this modified code:

```
def subset_sum(seq, target):
    left, right = seq[0], seq[1:]
    return target in (0, left) or \
        (bool(right) and (subset_sum(right, target - left) or subset_sum(right, target)))

def subset_sum_mem(seq, target, mem=None):
    mem = mem or {}
    key = (len(seq), target)
    if key not in mem:
        left, right = seq[0], seq[1:]
        mem[key] = target in (0, left) or \
            (bool(right) and (subset_sum_mem(right, target - left, mem) or subset_sum_mem(right, target, mem)))
    return mem[key]
```

Can you provide some test cases this does not work for?

Comment: it works great! thank you very much. in order to understand the solution in depth can you please explain what the return line does? return target in (0, left) or \
        (bool(right) and (subset_sum(right, target - left) or subset_sum(right, target)))

Comment: If this is homework, then you should figure out how that works -- and how it is identical to your original code.

Comment: The only thing i don't understand is what bool(right) gives to the solution. Can you explain?

Comment: Hmmmm. I was getting `[]` as a return value at some point in my experimentation, so I cast `right` to a bool. Now I can't come up with a case where it is needed.

Comment: Change `bool(right)` to `right` and try: `subset_sum([2], 1)` and `subset_sum_mem([2], 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd write the `subset_sum`:

```
def subset_sum(seq, target):
    if target == 0:
        return True

    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if subset_sum(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:], target - seq[i]):
            return True
    return False
```

It worked on a couple of examples:

```
>>> subset_sum([-1,1,5,4], 0))
True
>>> subset_sum([-1,1,5,4], 10)
True
>>> subset_sum([-1,1,5,4], 4)
True
>>> subset_sum([-1,1,5,4], -3)
False
>>> subset_sum([-1,1,5,4], -4)
False
```

To be honest I wouldn't know how to memoize it.

**Old Edit:** I removed the solution with `any()` because after some tests I found out that to be slower!

**Update:** Just out of curiosity you could also use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

def com_subset_sum(seq, target):
    if target == 0 or target in seq:
        return True

    for r in range(2, len(seq)):
        for subset in combinations(seq, r):
            if sum(subset) == target:
                return True
    return False
```

This can do better that the dynamic programming approach in some cases but in others it will hang (it's anyway better then the recursive approach).

Comment: `subset_sum = lambda seq, target: (target == 0) or any(subset_sum(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:], target - v) for i, v in enumerate(seq))` for us masochists ;)

Memoization is actually trivial dictionary lookup in this case. Nice solution!

Comment: Or: `    return any(subset_sum(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:], target - seq[i])
        for i in range(len(seq)))`

Comment: @user1123417: You're welcome, if you find it useful you can up-vote it (as a reward for our effort), and if it was the most useful one in solving your problem you can also accept it *(green arrow on the left)* :)